# Generating random integers in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to generate a random number in c++ using a modern approach.However i get the same random number every time i call the function

```
int getRandomPixel() {
    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 255); // define the range
    return distr(eng);
}
```

Comment: [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07af22f92a3ea8c0)

Comment: There's no need to recreate the device (`rd`) or the generator (`eng`) every call.

Comment: Are you using MinGW?

Comment: @BaummitAugen yes

Comment: In this case see [Why do I get the same sequence for every run with std::random\_device with mingw gcc4.8.1?](//stackoverflow.com/q/18880654)

Answer (score -1):

Your `std::random_device` is a PRNG, as stated [on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device):

> `std::random_device` may be implemented in terms of an
>   implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a
>   non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to
>   the implementation. **In this case each `std::random_device` object may
>   generate the same number sequence.**

On each call of `getRandomPixel()` you recreate the `rd` which will then produce the same first seed each time which will in turn produce the same value when your `mt19937` is seeded with that value because that's recreated as well and thus has the same initial state.

You should not recreate them each call:

```
int getRandomPixel() {
    static std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    static std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 255); // define the range
    return distr(eng);
}
```

Comment: That's not particularly useful; you'd still get the same sequence on every run of the program. Better wait until OP clarifies the platform, then we can hammer.

Comment: @BaumMitAugen You're quite right. I voted for you as mod so maybe we can settle this over a coffee.

Comment: Thanks for the vote, I highly appreciate it! With the question, there's nothing to do until OP clarifies I guess, but coffee always sounds lovely.

Answer (score -1):

The following solves the problem.I believe the issue was that i was recreating the device and the generator in every call

```
using u16  = unsigned short int;
u16 getRandomPixel() {
    static std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    static std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<u16> distr(0, 255); // define the range
    return distr(eng);
}
```

Comment: Do you not get the same sequence on every run of the program now? This is not really a workaround for the MinGW `random_device` issue.